# String was not recognized as a valid DateTime. Existing solutions have not worked for me

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I have googled this all morning but could not resolve it.

Infact, the solution I am trying below was extracted from this site:

```
 If e.Row.RowType = DataControlRowType.DataRow Then
 Dim eDate As TextBox = DirectCast(e.Row.FindControl("txtEventDate"), TextBox)
 eDate.Text = Request.QueryString("evdates")
 DateTime.ParseExact(eDate.Text, "MM/dd/yyyy", CultureInfo.CurrentCulture)
End If
```

The date value displays as `14/04/2014 00:00:00` but we would like to display as MM/dd/yyyy.

But we keep getting ***String was not recognized as a valid DateTime.***

I even tried doing this on the markup but to no avail.

```
<asp:TextBox ID="txtEventDate" DataFormatString="{0:d}" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
```

Any ideas how to fix this?

Comment: What is returned from `Request.QueryString("evdates")`, That doesn't match the format you are providing for parsing.

Comment: do you think `14` is a valid value for month?  If you use `TryParse` it wont throw the exception and will attempt to parse form all the valid formats for the current culture.  `Try/ParseExact` is more for cases when you know the exact input pattern, which is not the case here.

Answer (score 1):

From your question, it looks like the date is in the format of dd/MM/yyyy.  British style. Also you might want to use [CultureInfo.InvariantCulture](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.cultureinfo.invariantculture(v=vs.110).aspx). I am not sure where your IIS server is hosted or what culture is configured on the box.

You can try this:

```
// read the data from the request
string temp = Request.QueryString("evdates");

// convert the string to datetime object
DateTime d = DateTime.ParseExact(temp, "MM/dd/yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);

// format any way you like
eDate.Text = d.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy);
```

Comment: Not "British" - it's used all over the world. Only the US and Belize use MDY consistently.

Comment: @BlackFrog, it is my understanding that we can't use ParseExact the way we are using.

Your solution throws the same error that my was throwing.

Comment: I guess I could have saved myself a headache and downvote by handling this on the SQL side of things. Here is the code - just did in sql: `SELECT (CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), eventDates, 101)) AS eventDates FROM mytable` Now, I don't have to do any of this Parsing stuff. Thanks all for your contributions.